# Just installed vsftpd but it isn't showing in services

Tags: linux, service, ftp

I have installed vsftpd and configured as per several tutorials (just the very basic, standard setup) but when I run `cat /etc/services` there is nothing appearing for Port 21.

What steps do I need to follow in order to add this in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/etc/services` file is just text. You can edit it using your favourite text editor. My CentOS system has the following for ftp

```
ftp-data        20/tcp
ftp-data        20/udp
# 21 is registered to ftp, but also used by fsp
ftp             21/tcp
ftp             21/udp          fsp fspd
```

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/services` does not provide you a real-time list your server has running.

Use `netstat -tlnp` to see processes listening on some network ports.

Comment: Thanks, I ran that and noticed my Local Address for :21 is 0.0.0.0, should this not be 127.0.0.1?

Comment: 0.0.0.0 means "listen on all addresses available on this server". 127.0.0.1 would mean you only could contact your server from localhost and not from the outside world.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to open up `/etc/services` in a text editor and add it.  There's nothing special that needs to be done.  I'm incredibly surprised that it's not in there already; try a `grep` for `ftp`.